# Switching wireless card from Killer 1535 to Intel 9260 on a Dell XPS 9550

Tags: wifi, intel, dell

The stock Killer card is a bit unstable, it randomly disconnects, rarely but still.

I was thinking to switch to an Intel 9260 but should I install Intel drivers before switching cards? If so, how?

I am expecting the new Intel card to work automatically with elementary OS. I will no go through a fresh install just for this.

Much obliged.

Comment: No one? Everybody and their mother are switching out the Killer card, no elementary OS users? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I went ahead and bought an Intel AX200NGW, the latest and greatest AFAIK, supporting Wi-Fi 6 ax and Bluetooth 5.1.

Just placed it in my XPS, worked out of the box right away, no drivers needed, so upgrade with no worries.